# trouble with using css to properly display text below an image

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]

I am making a portfolio website and my goal is that each image of a project has a description below it matching that image as i scroll through the project carousel

whenever I use flex, it makes each description fall under the first image, and when i hit my scroll arrows the text goes away with the first image but the second and third image still display

does anyone have any advice for getting an even amount of space between these paragraphs using css?
My goal is to have 2 of the 3 paragraphs extend off screen, I have tried using the gap css method with flexbox but it wont make it even depeneding how big the browser window is

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { 
    faChevronLeft, 
    faChevronRight, 
    faCircle 
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

import { faCircle as emptyCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

import smartbrain from '../../assets/smartbrain.png';
import clipz from '../../assets/clipz.png';
import crwn from '../../assets/crwn.png';

import './projects.styles.css';

const slides = [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: "smartbrain",
        image: smartbrain,
        desc: "smartbrain Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit dicta exercitationem, sapiente voluptatum distinctio minima ratione eum sunt excepturi. Ipsum harum tenetur consequatur obcaecati iste! Ut aspernatur laudantium pariatur necessitatibus."
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "clipz",
        image: clipz,
        desc: "clipz Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit dicta exercitationem, sapiente voluptatum distinctio minima ratione eum sunt excepturi. Ipsum harum tenetur consequatur obcaecati iste! Ut aspernatur laudantium pariatur necessitatibus."
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "crwn",
        image: crwn,
        desc: " crwn Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit dicta exercitationem, sapiente voluptatum distinctio minima ratione eum sunt excepturi. Ipsum harum tenetur consequatur obcaecati iste! Ut aspernatur laudantium pariatur necessitatibus."
    }
]



const ProjectImages = () => {

    const [card, setCard] = useState(0);

    const previousCard = () => 
        setCard((card) => card === 0 ? slides.length - 1 : card - 1);

    const nextCard = () => 
        setCard((card) => card === slides.length - 1 ? 0 : card + 1);
    
    const cardDisplay = slides.map((item) => (
        <img key={item.id} src={item.image} alt={item.title} />
    ));

    const descDisplay = slides.map((words) => (
        <p key={words.id}>
            {words.desc}
        </p>
    ));



    return(

        <div className="information">

            <div className="image-container">
                <div 
                    className="image-display"
                    style = {{ transform: `translate(-${card * 100}%)` }}
                >
                    {cardDisplay}
                </div>
                <div className="button-container">
                    <button onClick={previousCard}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} size="2xl" />
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={nextCard}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronRight} size="2xl" />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="slide-container">
                    <div className="slide-dots" >
                        {slides.map((_, i) => (
                            card === i ? 
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} /> 
                            : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={emptyCircle} /> 
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="desc-container">
                <div 
                    className="desc-display"
                    style = {{ transform: `translate(-${card * 100}%)` }}
                >
                    {descDisplay}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    )
}

export default ProjectImages;
```

```
.information {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}


.image-container {

    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}

.image-display {
    display: flex;
    transition: 500ms ease;

}

.image-display img {
    min-width: 100%;

}


.image-container .button-container {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    inset: 0;

}

.desc-container {
    
    overflow: visible;

}

.desc-display {

    transition: 500ms ease;
    display: flex;

}

.desc-display p {
    padding: 0;
}


.slide-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 1vh;
}

.slide-dots {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 500ms ease;
    gap: 0.5vw;
}

button {

    border: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: 0 .3em;

}
```

Comment: Can you share working example, coz it's difficult to get the gist of what you want for reading your explanation.

Comment: `flex-direction: column` tries to stick to one column. Have you tried wrapping the description in a flex row with justify-content for spacing? Could also try grid layout, but row seems like it'd do it.

Comment: the best way to describe it cause i dont have a working example to go off of at the moment, is that you see how I have 3 different paragraphs that are stacked side by side under the image? i need those to extend off the screen

Comment: actually, i figured out how to accomplish my goal, i just set  the min-width to 100%

Comment: perhaps self-answer this question